# How to cast a Javascript String to SQL LongText

Tags: javascript, sql, string, longtext

I am facing a problem for an hour or so with a `LongText` column in SQL.
I am currently working on a web project where at some point we have a search form which allows user to search through numerous fields. Due to the customer's users being forced to use IE 9, we had to create a javascript... script, that parse the whole form and only takes what's needed in order not to exceed the 2k characters limit IE has.

So far so good, the script was working fine until we added a `textarea` field which represents a `LongText` column in our DB. The problem seems to come from the fact SQL won't take a simple `String` in an SQL statement as a LongText.

Here is what the query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM SONORA.CF_CPR_CASE WHERE CASEFOLDERID != 2 
and CMF_VLM_APPLICATION like '%CPR%' and CPR_DESCRIPTION='rererere'
and CMF_TYPE_CASE_FK like '%LC_130125_074927_000001_60%'
```

But I get this error:

```
EJBException:; nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The data types ntext
and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.S_EXCP(204); nested
exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: The data types ntext and varchar
are incompatible in the equal to operator.S_EXCP(204)

Found in FmsQuery: SELECT * FROM {{DBTABLEPREFIX}}CF_CPR_CASE WHERE
CASEFOLDERID != 2 and CMF_VLM_APPLICATION like '%CPR%' and 
CPR_DESCRIPTION='ztztztztz' and CMF_TYPE_CASE_FK like 
'%LC_130125_074927_000001_60%'
```

We are using CASE360 which is not so known but still doesn't matter much, we are building the "where clause" of the SQL statement through javascript and then send it to the CASE360 processor which will take this all and execute the query. This part works fine, it's just the LongText column which is giving me a hard time.

If you guys have any idea what this SQL Query should look like to be successfully interpreted then I'd be infinitely happy!

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You have SQL statements on the client-side, in JavaScript code?

Comment: Well no, we are building the SQL Where clause client-side, then with some magic tricks we give it to the server which then executes it and gives the result. But that ain't the point here

Comment: You're right that it isn't the point, but it's still pretty scary.

Comment: Well this is 100% safe in our case since the customer won't have any interest in hacking their own system.

Comment: Why aren't using a query and then refering to that through the using the servlets or caseajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a `CAST` on the column which is `ntext`. It's not clear to me which column that would be from the error above. As an example, let's assume it's the `CPR_DESCRIPTION` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM SONORA.CF_CPR_CASE
WHERE CASEFOLDERID != 2 
  and CMF_VLM_APPLICATION like '%CPR%'
  and CAST(CPR_DESCRIPTION as varchar(2000)) ='rererere'
  and CMF_TYPE_CASE_FK like '%LC_130125_074927_000001_60%'
;
```

Keep in mind that you need to pick an appropriately large `varchar` size for the cast, and that even with the maximum size there is a potential for data loss.

Comment: I'll try that, and you're right, sorry, it's the CPR_DESCRIPTION which is LongText.